# kernel init without 'root=' parameter

Tags: linux-kernel, systemd, fstab, root-filesystem

From [systemd/fstab-generator.c](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/fstab-generator/fstab-generator.c) it follows that systemd treats `root=` as required kernel parameter, the only configuration source for `/sysroot` mount. However from [kernel/init/main.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/main.c) and [kernel/init/do_mounts.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/do_mounts.c) it is not clear if that is so. Question: how can one do kernel init without 'root=' parameter (and tell systemd to support it)?

See: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3551

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`do_mounts.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/do_mounts.c?v=4.5), the variable `saved_root_name` is set to the value of the `root=` command line parameter, if present. This value is a path-like string [passed by the kernel](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/do_mounts.c?v=4.5#L210), it typically looks like `/dev/something` (though the `/dev/` prefix is optional) but it doesn't actually correspond to any on-disk path. If the `root=` parameter is absent, the value of `ROOT_DEV` is used; this is normally 0 but a different value can be injected in the system binary. The `util-linux` toolchain used to include a utility called [`rdev](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rdev&sektion=8&manpath=Linux+Slackware+3.1) to do this (on x86 only) but
[it disappeared a few years ago](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/commit/?id=a3e40c14651fccf18e7954f081e601389baefe3f).

All of this happens only if the [initramfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt) or [initrd](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/initrd.txt) hasn't taken care of mounting the root (initramfs by running `/init` which is supposed to call `mount`, initrd by calling `pivot_root`).

I don't know about the systemd part. There isn't much that systemd can do about the root filesystem anyway apart from mounting it read-write.

Comment: just to clarify: in scenario when : 1) parameter `root=` is missing, and 2) using `initramfs` with `/init`, then options are : 3) either the `/init` process must `mount` actual `/sysroot` as `r/w` to the `ROOT_DEV` (which is defined at kernel build time as `major:minor=0:0`), or : 4) `/init` can set `ROOT_DEV` in the live kernel to point to the actual `/sysroot`, and : 5) there are no tools available for the `/init` to actually set `ROOT_DEV` value for #4. correct? finally : 6) are there tools which allow `/init` to read `ROOT_DEV` value from the live kernel for #3?

Comment: @AndreiPozolotin `ROOT_DEV` can't be set at runtime, it can only be set in the kernel image on disk. I don't think it can be read either. If there's a `/init` on the initramfs, `ROOT_DEV` isn't used anyway.

Comment: you mean that in scenario #1 / #2 : `/init` need only discover/prepare actual `/sysroot`, then [switch_root](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/switch_root.8.html) form `initramfs` root `/` to the actual `/sysroot` , and kernel is not involved in rootfs setup via `do_mounts.c`  /  `ROOT_DEV` at all?

Comment: @AndreiPozolotin Yes: `prepare_namespace` is called only if there is no `/init` on the initramfs.

Comment: great, thank you. please update your answer to reflect `switch_root`. so all the code I see in the various `/init` implementations (including `systemd`) which deals with `root=` parameter is there merely by convention, and not because the kernel will use this parameter (when `/init` is present).

Comment: @AndreiPozolotin I did mention `switch_root` in my answer, just not by name. The `switch_root` utility calls the ordinary `mount` system call to mount a new root filesystem over the rootfs, it isn't like initramfs for which there's a separate system call `pivot_root` that exchanges `/` with another mount point.

Comment: @Gilles how _did_ you get a kernel to boot without a `root=` parameter? In theory, if I pass it `initrd=`, I should be exempt from a `root=`, but the kernel complains that it is required.